# How to use more than once the stdin with a "-" (dash) in a bash script?

Tags: bash, pipe, stdin

I'm writing a bash script whose input can be given through pipe, for this I use "-" but it can be used once. I tried to save it in a variable with `input=$(cat -)` but I am worried that if the input file is very large it may have problems. I would like to know the best way to use the input that "-" gives me.

The idea of the script is to do something like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
a=(cat - | grep -c "whatever")
b=(cat - | grep -c "whatever")
c=$(echo "($a+$b)" | bc)
echo "$c"
```

Comment: You can probably use it as needed, just `read`ing lines (or chunks) as you go. But it might depend how the script works. What does the script look like? Could you provide something like a [mre]? You can [edit] the question. BTW welcome to SO! Check out the [tour].

Comment: stdin (when a FIFO rather than a seekable file descriptor) can only be read once -- once it's been read, it's no longer available for any other program to read! Of course, you can read it _into a variable_ and store that variable to replay multiple times; but that'll mean your program needs to store that content in memory (whereas usually a pipe buffer is very small; beyond that buffer, content isn't produced by the program on the left-hand side of the pipe until the program on the right is ready to read it, so you can pipe documents much larger than memory).

Comment: You also don't need `bc` to do simple integer addition... `c=$((a+b))`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default, `cat` reads its standard input. So "-" is not needed.

If you need to "grep" two regular expressions from the input, you can use `grep` without `cat` as it reads its standard input by default as well.

If the goal is to count the number of occurrences of two different patterns in the input, the equivalent of what you are trying to do could be something like:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
grep -c -E '(whatever1|whatever2)'
```

As pointed out in the comments, if the requirement is also to take in account multiple occurrences of the patterns in the lines and both patterns in the same lines, the "-o" option of `grep` can be used:

> -o, --only-matching
> Print only the matched (non-empty) parts of a matching line, with each such part on a separate output line

With such an option, the output of `grep` is as many lines as there are matching patterns. So, the enhanced code counts those lines with `wc -l` and displays the result:

```sh
#!/bin/bash
grep -o -E '(whatever1|whatever2)' | wc -l
```

Comment: Output will be a little different. If one grep counts lines with As and the other counts lines with Bs, a line "AB" would add 2 to the output of the original code, but only 1 to the output of this code.

Comment: When you also want nultible occurrences in one line, you might want `echo "w1 w1 w2 w1" | grep  -o -E '(w1|w2)' | wc -l`.

Comment: Thank you for your comments, the answer has been enhanced accordingly.